# How to maintain 1 char at a time when holding down delete?

Tags: keyboard

After about 2 seconds or so quickly deleting 1 char at a time holding down delete turns into quickly delete entire words or sentences at a time. To avoid this I end up having to:

press for about 1 second
then let go

press for about 1 second
then let go

press for about 1 second
then let go

Is there a way to change the behavior to maintain only 1 char at a time no matter how long you hold it down? Maybe have another key delete entire words or sentences at a time. This is using the Samsung keyboard, is there another keyboard that'll allow this?

Answer (score 1):

This is a 'feature' of Samsung's keyboard, default on Samsung android phones. I did look at Samsung's settings and did not see the ability to alter this. Use another keyboard to fix, which I did, such as Gboard by Google.

While I do like the ability quickly delete word by word also, that should be provided by a another key, not shared with the character by character key.